# Python class utilizing the singleton method

Tags: python, class, oop, logging, singleton

Trying to understand how to create a single instance of a logging class in a separate module. I am trying to access the logging module from my python script. So, I have different files in this automation script and I am trying to record the logs in a file and displaying the logs in the console at the same time so I would be utilizing two handlers namely: FileHandler() and StreamHandler(). The initialization of logger is in a different file called debugLogs.py and I am accessing this file from multiple Python modules running the script. But if the separate modules call debugLogs.py it creates multiple instances of the logger which means it gets printed multiple times which is not what I want. That is why I need to use singleton method to create just one instance. How do you suggest I go about doing that? Should I create a method inside class called setLogger and use it to initialize logger, if so how to do declare method inside a singleton class? I have included my version of debugLogs.py in this code and I have shown:

```
#debugLogs.py

import logging
import logging.handlers

#open readme file and read name of latest log file created
def get_name():
    with open("latestLogNames.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            pass
        latestLog = line
    logfile_name = latestLog[:-1]
    return logfile_name


class Logger(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(self, logfile_name):
        if not self._instance:
            self._instance = super(Logger, self).__new__(self)
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
            file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile_name)
            file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
            stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            logger.addHandler(file_handler)
            logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
        return self._instance
```

So get_name() gets the latest log name already indicated in the readme file latestLogNames.txt and inputs the logs in the latest log file already there. I understand that my singleton class code is not right and I am confused on how to initialize the whole class structure. But somehow I would have to pass that logfile_name value to that class. So I am planning to call this logger from a different module with something like this:

```
#differentModule.py

import debugLogs
logger = debugLogs.Logger(debugLogs.get_name())
```

And then I would use logger.info("...") to print the logs as well as store it in the file. Please tell me how to restructure the debugLogs.py and how to call it from different modules of my script.

Comment: Usually you configure logging once and the you run `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` once in every module. That's all.

Comment: @KlausD. But that is exactly what I do not want as that creates multiple instances and the same logs are printed multiple lines in my log file. I feel that the singleton method is the only way to create a single instance. And I am calling the debugLogs.py from all the modules and there are 8 modules calling this debugLogs.py.

Comment: Then you have not configured the root logger properly. You will not get a singleton logger since the logging system creates objects on its own.

Comment: @KlausD. Any ideas on how I can configure the logger such that it does not create different objects and I can log the statements through one single object so one line gets printed in accordance to one instance